# Ionic Error Fetching Local API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an Ionic App that fetches from an external API. Because this API is also developed by myself, everything is local. The API returns a JSON array.

My current controller looks like following:

```
app.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
       $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getPoi/merzouga').success(function(data){
       $scope.pois = data;
   });
}]);
```

The problem is that when I try to load this into my view I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/getPoi/merzouga. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I don't know if it is relevant, but Ionic is being served on port 8100 and the API on 8080.

Any idea on how can I test this locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install and enable [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) plugin in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is telling you how to solve the problem. Since you have the API in a different port, you need to send the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header along with your response (server-side). Supposing you are using Express, it'll be like this:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Or even better, you can just use a middleware for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors